# Past continuous or simple past tense

Tags: grammar, past-tense

I was having a shower when the telephone rang. (Past Continuous for interrupted action)
I was in the shower when the telephone rang.

Why is Past Simple used in the second sentence?)

Comment: It seems reasonable.  "I was taking a shower" describes my state of being when the phone rang; so does "I was in the shower."  What would the alternative be? "I was being in the shower" would be just extra words and clunky.

Comment: Progressive constructions require semantically active verbs like _take a shower_. Locative predicates are stative, not active, and therefore don't allow the progressive. This is in fact one of the tests for active vs stative predicates: _I am renting that house_ (_rent_ is active) vs *_I am owning that house,_ which is ungrammatical because _own_ is stative.

Comment: Oh, just looked at the actual question. The second sentence is not progressive because the phone ringing is a punctual event, not a durative one. Durative events like showering take some time to accomplish, and hence are fine with the progressive. But if you use a punctual verb with the progressive (e.g, _the phone was ringing_), you give the impression that it went on for a long time and that other things were going on hurriedly at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good explanation of why the progressive can't be used; it is found in *A comprehensive grammar of the English language*. It must be understood first that the verb "to be" in the sentence is a so called *stative verb*.

> (CoGEL § **4.26**) **State, event, and habit with the progressive**
>
> The three verb senses of state, event, and habit are differently interpreted
> with the progressive :
> (a) STATE PROGRESSIVE
> In many cases the progressive is unacceptable with stative verbs:
> ♦ We own a house in the country.
> ♦ *We are owning a house in the country.
> ♦ *Sam's wife was being well-dressed.
> This can be explained, in part, by the observation that stative verb meanings
> are inimical to the idea that some phenomenon is 'in progress'. States are
> 'like-parted' in that every segment of a state has the same character as any
> other segment: no progress is made. (Contrast We are building a house in the
> country.) Where the progressive does occur, it is felt to imply temporariness
> rather than permanence:
> ♦ We are living in the country. [temporary residence]
> ♦ We live in the country. [permanent residence]

Comment: Agree with this answer 100%.